# A Variant of the QR Decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

This is exercise P5.2.6 from Matrix Computations 4ed, Golub and Van Loan:

Suppose $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $D = \mathrm{diag}(d_1, \cdots, d_n) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. Give a procedure to calculate an orthogonal $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ s.t.
$$
R := Q^TA - DQ^T
$$
is upper triangular.

I tried different ideas:

1. Use induction on the dimension $n$, where in each step the Householder reflection / Givens rotation is applied;
2. Split $Q = [q_1 | q_2 | \cdots | q_n]$ into column vectors, substitute into $Q^TA - DQ^T = R$ , then solve for $Q$ and $R$;
3. Make use of the original QR decomposition;

but none of them seems the right path. Any hint is appreciated !

Comment: What is $R$ here?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net The exercise requires $R := Q^TA - DQ^T$ to be upper triangular. Maybe I should write it in a clearer way.

Comment: The comment beneath it says "Do not worry about efficiency-this is just an exercise in QR manipulation.". I would suspect you could rewrite the original Gram-Schmidt method at 5.2.7

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the equation

$$ R = Q^{T}A - DQ^{T}$$
$$ QR = A - QDQ^{T} $$
$$ A = QR + QDQ^{T}$$

Then the basic $QR$ decomposition corresponds to when $D = \mathbb{0}$.

Comment: The question is about how to compute $Q$ and $R$ if $D\neq 0$.

Comment: I understand that. The person asked for a hint and the book says it's an exercise in QR manipulation.